# Workflow Manager - Request response workflow

Tags: .net, windows, workflow-foundation

Is there any way to implement request response workflows using Workflow Manager 1.0?

"Workflow Manager 1.0 does not currently support direct SOAP messaging, including two-way (request-response) communication." however wondering if that means it is not possible, I couldn't find any sample though

Thanks

Comment: This might be of some help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj193461(v=azure.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks Ryan I had a look, and it looks like there it had no hay at the moment to implement request response support, sad feeling, was really looking forward to take advantage of Windows Service Bus and Workflow Manager to expose our services